# how to implement linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, structure, doubly-linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node {
int data;
struct Node* next;
struct Node* prev;
};

void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) {
struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
new_node->data = new_data;
new_node->next = (*head_ref);
new_node->prev = NULL;
if ((*head_ref) != NULL)(*head_ref)->prev = new_node;
(*head_ref) = new_node;}

void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data){
    /* 1. allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* last = *head_ref; /* used in step 5*/
    /* 2. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;
    /* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so
        make next of it as NULL*/
    new_node->next = NULL;
    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new
        node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL) {
        new_node->prev = NULL;
        *head_ref = new_node;
        return;}
    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;
    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_node;
    /* 7. Make last node as previous of new node */
    new_node->prev = last;
    return;}

void insertAfter(struct Node* prev_node, int new_data){
/*1. check if the given prev_node is NULL */
if (prev_node == NULL) {
    printf("the given previous node cannot be NULL");
    return;}
/* 2. allocate new node */
struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
/* 3. put in the data */
new_node->data = new_data;
/* 4. Make next of new node as next of prev_node */
new_node->next = prev_node->next;
/* 5. Make the next of prev_node as new_node */
prev_node->next = new_node;
/* 6. Make prev_node as previous of new_node */
new_node->prev = prev_node;
/* 7. Change previous of new_node's next node */
if (new_node->next != NULL)
    new_node->next->prev = new_node;}

void printList(struct Node* node){
    struct Node* last;
    printf("\nTraversal in forward direction \n");
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf(" %d ", node->data);
        last = node;
        node = node->next;}

    printf("\nTraversal in reverse direction \n");
    while (last != NULL) {
        printf(" %d ", last->data);
        last = last->prev;
    }}


void sortedInsert(struct Node** head, int new_data) {

    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    struct Node* temp;

    if ((*head) == NULL || (new_node->data) > (*head)->prev->data) {
        append(head, new_data);
        return;
    }

    if ((new_node->data) < ((*head)->data)) {
        push(head, new_data);
        return;
    }

    temp = (*head)->next;
    while ((temp->data) < (new_node->data)) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    insertAfter(head, new_data);
}
int main() {
struct Node* head = NULL;
sortedInsert(&head, 0);
sortedInsert(&head, 9);
sortedInsert(&head, 4);
sortedInsert(&head, 3);
sortedInsert(&head, 34);
sortedInsert(&head, 15);
printf("\n Created Linked list is: ");
printList(head);
return 0;}
```

I am trying to write a C program where data must be inserted in a ordered way (smaller to higher) 
When I run the code program gives error due to the note:
expected 'struct Node *' but argument is of type 'struct Node **' 
how can I fix this problem , I have looked up to the other solutions such as : [What does the warning - expected ‘struct node **’ but argument is of type ‘struct node **’ mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245936/what-does-the-warning-expected-struct-node-but-argument-is-of-type-struc) 
but those couldnt resolve my issue. 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: In the call `insertAfter(head, new_data);`, `head` is `struct Node **`, but the expected type of the first argument per the declaration and implementation of `insertAfter` is `struct Node *`. The warning is telling you you're not passing a value of the proper type, and the warning is entirely accurate in that assessment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     insertAfter(head, new_data);
> ```
>
> how can I fix this problem

You forgot to dereference `struct Node** head` as you correctly did at other places in the function `sortedInsert`; to get the argument type right, it would be `insertAfter(*head, new_data)`.

But still the insertion logic isn't quite right; here's a corrected version:

```
void sortedInsert(struct Node** head, int new_data) {

    // new node is allocated in append(), push() or insertAfter()
    struct Node* temp;

    if ((*head) == NULL || new_data < (*head)->data) {
        push(head, new_data);
        return;
    }

    temp = *head;
    while (temp->next && temp->next->data < new_data) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    insertAfter(temp, new_data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the functions you declared you should pass a reference (address) to the head not the head itself as this what your code requires.

As an example, use `append(&head, 3)` instead of `append(head, 3)`

Comment: As I understand it for functions that takes *head  as its input you should use head (for example inside the main function printList(head) )and for functions that takes **head as its input you should use *head as you mentioned before.But when you use the functions inside another functions it gets complicated , I tried your solution and when I make changes you mentioned inside the sortedInsert function it creates a new error :   argument is of type ‘struct Node ***’ Before any change there is only one error which is created due to insertAfter so I think append and push should remain as they are